# Using modify/update creates inconsistent data

Tags: updates, drools

I am getting inconsistent data in the List, the data in the list added in the Rule 1. Rule 2 modifies the object which holds the list, due to the update/modify the Rules get called repeatedly.

```
rule "Rule 1"
dialect "java"
no-loop true
when
    $notification:NotificationVO();
    $snrData : SensorDataVO(getOffsetChngesInterval()!=null,
                            getOffsetChngesInterval().size()>0);
    $pestWeight:Integer() from $snrData.getOffsetChngesInterval();
    $masterData: MasterDataVO($pestWeight==rodentWeight);
then
    System.out.println("Rule 2");
    modify($notification){getFilteredMasterData().add($masterData)};
end

rule "Rule 2"
dialect "java" 
no-loop true
when
    $notification: NotificationVO(getFilteredMasterData()!=null,
                                  getFilteredMasterData().size()>3,
                                  getReasoningData().size()==0);
then
  System.out.println("Rule 3");
  modify($notification) {
    getReasoningData().put($notification.getFilteredMasterData().get(0)
 .getRodentWeight(),
                           $notification.getFilteredMasterData().get(0))
  }
end
```

Can you please tell me what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple: whenever a fact is modified, all rules referencing that fact are evaluated again, and if the condition is true, they result in another activation.

To break this vicious circle, you have several options, but using no-loop on both rules isn't one of them.

First, you can add the condition that one of the rules establishes by its right hand side isn't given in the fact data. So, as `Rule 1` adds `$masterData` to the list `filteredMasterData`: add the constraint that this element is absent from the list:

```
when
  $notification:NotificationVO( $fmd: filteredMasterData)
  $snrData : SensorDataVO(getOffsetChngesInterval()!=null,
                          getOffsetChngesInterval().size()>0)
  $pestWeight:Integer() from $snrData.getOffsetChngesInterval()
  $masterData: MasterDataVO($pestWeight==rodentWeight)
  eval( ! $fmd.contains( $masterData ) )
then
```

Another possibility depends on the use of the Map reasoningData that is updated in `Rule 2`. If this is *not used in any condition*, you can simply modify the Map *without calling update or modify*, doing (what I call) a "dirty update".

Comment: Thanks Laune, I have removed the dirty updating code. I am not going to use the map reasoningData in the LHS side no need to update it.